# How would I integrate the following integral?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt[5]{1-x^{5}}}
$$

Or any integral of this type.

Comment: Have you learned about trigonometric substitution yet?

Comment: Yes, is that what I should use?

Comment: Are you trying to determine if the integral converges or diverges? You're not going to find an antiderivative with elementary functions.

Comment: I have to test it's convergence, but I also have to calculate it.

Comment: I'm with @TedShifrin, I doubt there is a nice way to compute the antiderivative.

Comment: @KeeferRowan, it can be expressed in terms of hypergeometric function. Yet the integral doesn't converge.

Comment: You’re not integrating the integral; you’re integrating the *integrand*, the *function*. If you integrated the integral then you’d have a double integral. The verb you’re looking for is *evaluate* or *compute*.

Comment: @TedShifrin By Chebyshev's theorem, the integral of $x^m (a x^n + b)^p$ with $m, n, p \in \mathbb Q$ is elementary iff one of $p, \, (m + 1)/n, \, (m + 1)/n + p$ is an integer. If $(m + 1)/n + p \in \mathbb Z$, as in this case, and $r$ is the denominator of $p$, the substitution $u = (a + b x^{-n})^{1/r}$ gives a rational integrand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ n \in\mathbb{N}^{*} : $

Using $ \small\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}u&=x^{n}\\ \mathrm{d}x&=\frac{1}{n}u^{\frac{1}{n}-1}\,\mathrm{d}u\end{aligned}\right. $, we get

\begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt[n]{1-x^{n}}}}&=\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{1}{u^{\frac{1}{n}-1}\left(1-u\right)^{-\frac{1}{n}}\,\mathrm{d}u}=\frac{1}{n}\beta\left(\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n\Gamma\left(1\right)}=\frac{\pi}{n\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}}\end{aligned}

Comment: Thank you, very elegant solution!

Comment: @TudorPodina It turns out $\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{1+y^n}$ has the same value, this time via $u=\frac{1}{1+y^{-n}}$.

Comment: $\frac\pi5\csc\left(\frac\pi5\right)=\frac\pi{25}\sqrt{50+10\sqrt{5}}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to write down the antiderivative as some special function (in particular 2F1 hypergeometric function), but you don't need to evaluate the integral to prove it doesn't converge

> Hint: it acts like $1/x$

Edit:
After the change of integration limits, the integral converges.

So the new hint would be to look into the complex plane.

Comment: I know that it is not necessary for it's convergence. Unfortunately, I also need to evaluate it.

Comment: @TudorPodina it will diverge to $\pm\infty$. You just need to figure out which one, and then you have "evaluated" it.

Comment: It's impossible to evaluate the value of something non-converging. That's the definition of the convergence. If you want to assign the value, you need some kind of 'new' rule to remove non-converging part.

Comment: @TudorPodina if it dosen't converge then it's infinite. it dosent make sence to evaluate an integral that dosent converge to a certain value.

Comment: I made a mistake, the interval of integration is [0,1).